# OpenVPN. How to Provide Interactive Credentials in a Script

Tags: openvpn

I have a script that installs and sets up VPN then connects to it:

```
apt install apt-transport-https
wget https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub
apt-key add openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub
wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-focal.list
apt update
apt install openvpn3
openvpn3 session-start --config profile-59.ovpn
```

When I run it on Ubuntu Desktop it asks for credentials interactively:
[image]

How can I adjust the script to pass credentials avoiding interactive prompt? The purpose for this is to have a Docker container connect to VPN automatically.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `auth-user-pass` config option?

Comment: Never heard of it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to examine [something like `expect`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/expect.1.html), which would allow you to do something like this:

```
spawn vpn_connect.sh
expect "Auth User name:"
send "protractor-container\r"
expect "Password:"
send "superSecretPassword!123\r"
```

Of course this might not be ideal in the event a number of people have the ability to connect to the Docker container or read the source files that get packaged in the build, as clear text passwords can create problems.

One option would be to create a separate file that contains the credentials and store it in a location within the Docker container, such as `/root/.private/vpn-creds`. This file would contain just two lines:

```
protractor-container
superSecretPassword!123
```

Then you can edit your `expect` script to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set passfile [open "/root/.private/vpn-creds" r]
gets $passfile username
gets $passfile password
close $passfile

spawn vpn_connect.sh
expect "Auth User name:"
send "$username\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
```

Mind you, if everyone has `root` access, there’s not much you can do in an automated fashion to hide the credentials. A determined person with `sudo` who knows how to use StackExchange will find a way to get the information they want

Comment: That would require to store password in a file, right? Can we do that without it?

Comment: @WinBoss added a bit to show how to read credentials from elsewhere, with a caveat 